# Convert gpointer to QByteArray in QT

Tags: c++, qt, glib

How can I convert `gpointer` bytes (FT_BYTES) to `QByteArray` in Qt?
Point:

a) `gpointer` is a type like `void*` in glib Linux package.

b) A hex dump like `a0 23 5c` which is stored as `gpointer` and I like to convert it to hex in `QByteArray` format

Comment: Have you looked at the [`QByteArray` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-1) or [`QByteArray::fromRawData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromRawData)?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it to hex?" If I understand what you're trying to do, no conversion is necessary. The fromRawData() call that GM referenced is probably all you need, unless by "convert" you meant that you want to represent the data in hex format, in which case QByteArray isn't really a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
QByteArray createQBAfromGP(gpointer gp, int byteCount)
{
    return QByteArray::fromRawData((char *)gp, byteCount);
}
```

Be aware that the bytes are not copied. The `QByteArray` is merely a view into the original memory. If you want them copied, you can

```
QByteArray convertToQBA(gpointer gp, int byteCount)
{
    return QByteArray().append(QByteArray::fromRawData((char *)gp, byteCount));
}
```